# How to use RowMapper to insert record into table?

Tags: jdbctemplate

How to insert data into table using row mapper?

I am trying this:

```
Employee user1 = jtemplate.queryForObject("INSERT INTO employee(id, name,salary) VALUES(10,'ABC',12333);",new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Employee>(Employee.class));
```

It gives me bad SQL grammar error.

But query works in SQL developer. What I am doing wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO employee(id, name,salary) VALUES(99,'ABC',12333)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:466)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:476)
    at com.cts.orm.rowmapper.Test.main(Test.java:29)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Odscrarr.doODNY(T4C8Odscrarr.java:98)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doDescribe(T4CStatement.java:805)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.describe(OracleStatement.java:3978)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetMetaData.<init>(OracleResultSetMetaData.java:55)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getMetaData(OracleResultSetImpl.java:175)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.mapRow(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:240)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:455)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:400)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO employee(id, name,salary) VALUES(?,?,?)", 10, "ABC", 12333);
```

Comment: I know it works, I am trying to use `rowmapper` or `BeanPropertyRowMapper` with jdbctemplate, It works for fetching data. I just wanna know if it works for inserting as well.

Comment: no, it doesn't work for inserting. Anyway avoid of specifying string-values in query to protect from sql injection

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will settle for `jdbcTemplate.update`

Answer (score 3):

[`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) does what you want:

```java
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(
    "INSERT INTO employee(id, name, salary) VALUES (:id, :name, :salary)",
    new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(Employee.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the semi colon at the end of the statement should solve the problem use it like this. when using the jdbc templates it is not good to use semicolon at the end of sql statements

```
Employee user1 = jtemplate.queryForObject("INSERT INTO employee(id, name,salary) VALUES(10,'ABC',12333)",new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Employee>(Employee.class));
```

try using it like

```
    jtemplate.update("INSERT INTO Employee(ID, NAME, Salary) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
     new Object[] { employee.getId(), employee.getName(), employee.getSalary() });
```

i am using this and it works correctly and displays no errors

Comment: you cannot insert values using queryForObject.. you can only use 
`update()` to insert data/values into a table

Comment: @BappadityaSasmal   queryForObject can only be used to get data from a table it is an updated form of Select statement for more info about how to insert values in table you can check out this tutorial

 https://javabrains.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/spring-tutorial-42-performing-write-operations-with-jdbctemplate/